# Flask not aware of dynamically added input fields on first validation

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am adding new file upload fields dynamically via a button if the user clicks it.
Validation only passes on every second try and that's because flask/wtforms is not aware of the new dynamically created inputfields. Whenever I click my submit button it'll only warn for the very first field that the file is missing.

Once I put in all required files and submit, it fails on the first try, but afterwards the fieldlist has been initialized to the required size and it works the next time I submit the same amount of files.

**forms.py**

```
class ChildForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf = False

    childvalue1= IntegerField(default=1, validators=[DataRequired()])
    childvalue2= FileField(validators=[FileRequired(),FileAllowed(['mp3'])])


class ParentForm(FlaskForm):
    parentvalue1= FileField('PDF File', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['pdf'])])
    parentfieldlist= FieldList(FormField(ChildForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField('Upload')
```

**html file**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        <!-- PDF Upload -->
        <div>
            <label class="label">{{ form.parentvalue1.label }}</label>
            {{ form.parentvalue1}}
            <br>
        </div>

        <!-- Audio Upload -->
        <br>
        <div>
            <label class="label">{{ form.parentfieldlist.label }}</label>
            <table id="audiotable">
                {% for entry in form.parentfieldlist%}
                <tr>
                    {% for subfield in entry %}
                    <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>

        <br>
        <button type='button' class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
        <br><br>
        <p> {{ form.submit(class='button is-link') }}

    </form>
```

JS to create more input fields

```
<script>

    String.format = function () {
        var s = arguments[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
            var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
            s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
        }
        return s;
    }

    var fieldNum = 1;
    $('.add_more').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var firstTag = "parentfieldlist-" + fieldNum + "-childvalue1"
        var secondTag = "parentfieldlist-" + fieldNum + "-childvalue2"
        var rowTemplate = `<tr><td><input type='text' id=${firstTag } name=${firstTag } value=${fieldNum + 1} /></td>
            <td><input type='file' id=${secondTag } name=${secondTag }/></td></tr>`;
        $("#audiotable").append(rowTemplate);
        fieldNum++;
    });
    
</script>
```

Anyone happen to know how to make it work?
Another example. If I add a second upload field and submit, this is what my functions prints:

```
[{'childvalue1': 1, 'childvalue2': <FileStorage: 'somefile.mp3' ('audio/mpeg')>}, {'childvalue1': 2, 'childvalue2': None}]
```

If I do it again and submit, it'll work.
There are some hacky solutions with ajax calls to python functions where you use append_entry(), but I'm not convinced of those and uncertain whether they really solve the issue. In essence the file is always none on first submit

Edit: If I remove 'FileRequired' from childvalue 2 it doesn't work at all. Here's a pic to show what I mean

[image]

The form is not aware of the second upload field which I added via by button
Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer was VERY simple, but to me not that obvious.

`<input type='file' id=${secondTag } name=${secondTag }/>`

needs to be like this, just like the first childvalue, which I put in since it has a default value

`<input type='file' id=${secondTag } name=${secondTag } value=""/>`

Now Flask recognizes the dynamically added files on submit/validation. It should have been obvious from the beginning, since the first value has always been transmitted, but the second value was 'none' with the only difference being "value" between the two